# Running a cron to query if a user account has redeemed so many points within a week

Tags: mysql, cron

My system allows a user to enter a code to add points to their account. I wish to be notified whenever the user redeems more than 10,000 points within a week period.

I assume this requires a cron job, so I have set that up. I just wondered if theres some sort of mysql function to help me out with this at query-time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron command will look something like this:

```
mysql mydatabase -c "select username, sum(points) as points from redeemed where timestamp > subdate(now(), interval 7 day) group by 1"
```